# MYSQL - Insert strings limited by ','

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure

Table `Items`

[image]

Table `Sale`

[image]

And finally: Table `SaleItems`

[image]

Procedure `PLAYER_CREATE_SALE`:

IN paramters:

- in_player_id int
- in_total int
- in_items_ids nvarchar(500)
- in_items_quantity nvarchar(500)

Basically, the "user" see the list of the Items above, select any item, change the amount and buy. This should works like a "cart".

So, for example: User select bomb(id: 1, quantity: 10) and gear(id: 3, quantity: 2)

The parameters of my procedure would look like this:

`in_player_id: 750`

`in_total: 390`

`in_items_ids: "1,3"`

`in_items_quantity: "10,2"`

This is how works the procedure actually:

```
    INSERT INTO Sale(`player_id`, `total_coins_price`)
    VALUES(in_player_id, in_total);

    SET @sale_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    SET @squery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO SaleItems(`sale_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) 
SELECT ", @sale_id, ", id, 9999 FROM Items WHERE id IN (", in_items_ids, ")");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @squery;

    EXECUTE stmt;
```

With the code above the result final will be:

[image]

But the quantity is wrong. I don't know how insert the quantity too. Here is how should be:

[image]

Comment: From my app, the quantity can change but it will have always the same amount of items than 'in_items_ids'. For example, if in_items_ids have 4 values then in_items_quantity will have 4 values too.

Comment: select bomb(id: 1, quantity: 10) using this method quantity have single value

Comment: `SET @squery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO SaleItems(`sale_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) 
SELECT ", @sale_id, ", id, in_items_quantity FROM Items WHERE id IN (", in_items_ids, ")");`

Comment: Let me check...

Comment: So, using ```SET @squery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO SaleItems(`sale_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) 
SELECT ", @sale_id, ", id, in_items_quantity FROM Items WHERE id IN (", in_items_ids, ")");``` with the same values of above I get  [Err] 1265 - Data truncated for column 'quantity' at row 1

Comment: Try again by giving single value in field in_items_quantity

Comment: Yeah with single value it works but in_items_quantity sometimes have more than 1 value, how can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to go through loop inside procedure

Comment: What is the format for the quantity field? What is the data type?

Comment: Both are varchar and have this format 'value, value, value'

Answer (score 0):

Use your code inside loop and change line as:

```
SET @squery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO SaleItems(sale_id, item_id, quantity) SELECT ", @sale_id, ", id", in_items_quantity "FROM Items WHERE id IN (", in_items_ids, ")");
```

**The variable `in_items_quantity` should have single value.**

Comment: But I think If I do a loop this is going to insert more items than that actually are. For example, in_items_ids = '1,2,3' (3 values) in_items_quantity = '5,7,8'. If I do a loop for the 3 quantity then this is going to insert 3 rows with 1 - 5, 3 rows with 2 - 7 and other 3 with 3 - 8 because 'WHERE id IN ()'

Comment: IN clause is only for getting record based upon given values

Comment: Yes, but If I do the loop and put that code inside is going to insert more than that I need

Comment: I didn't write it yet since I'm trying to think because in_items_quantity is going to have 1 or more values always.

Comment: You have to pick values one by one from this list and insert via query inside loop